# ASP.NET MVC : the conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I click on the button to make a record in the database, I get this error:

> SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Controller:

```
   // GET: Reservas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        using (var ctx = new HotelEntities())
        {

            var quarto = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT DISTINCT Quarto.ID_Quarto FROM Quarto LEFT JOIN Reserva ON Quarto.ID_Quarto = Reserva.ID_Quarto WHERE Reserva.ID_Quarto IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Quarto Q2 LEFT JOIN Reserva R2 ON Q2.ID_Quarto = R2.ID_Quarto WHERE Quarto.ID_Quarto = Q2.ID_Quarto AND R2.DataEntrada <= GETDATE() AND(R2.DataSaida IS NULL OR R2.DataSaida > GETDATE()))").ToList();
            ViewBag.ID_Quarto = new SelectList(quarto, "ID_Quarto");
        }

        ViewBag.ID_Cliente = new SelectList(db.Cliente, "ID_Cliente", "Nome");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Reservas/Create
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Reserva reserva)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reserva.Add(reserva);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ID_Cliente = new SelectList(db.Cliente, "ID_Cliente", "Nome", reserva.ID_Cliente);
        ViewBag.ID_Quarto = new SelectList(db.Quarto, "ID_Quarto", "TipoQuarto", reserva.ID_Quarto);
        return View(reserva);
    }
```

Model class:

```
public partial class Reserva
{
        public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }
        public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public int ID_Quarto { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }
        public int NumeroPessoas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
        public string Observaçoes { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual Quarto Quarto { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Code First or Database First? The problem may lies in `DateTime DataEntrada` where you're not assigning any value to it, resulting the property has default `DateTime.MinValue` which is outside the range of SQL `DATETIME` data type minimum value (1970/01/01).

Comment: Okay, but the DataEntrada field is populated ... I do not understand the reason for the error.

Comment: You should check the value that `DataEntry` property (and other `DateTime` property) contains. The exception message is self-explanatory: one of your `DateTime` property contains `DateTime.MinValue` (0001/01/01) which is below minimum value of `DATETIME` SQL data type.

Comment: you ARE CORRECT, I checked what was going on and the data I fill in is all going to be null and the date in the wrong format hence the error. I do not understand, I'm inserting everything correctly

Comment: It depends on how view page bound to `Reserva` model (the page still not shown here). If you can provide view code probably submission problem can be handled accordingly.

Comment: here's the code on view https://jsfiddle.net/qcbxgru5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103566/asp-net-mvc-delete-button) and current view code in fiddle, clearly you're using `Html.BeginForm()` in the wrong way. You're actually putting only buttons inside `Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xl" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Registar"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Reservas")'" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Voltar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></button>
}
```

Since the form only contains buttons, then any other user input values are not submitted during POST and non-nullable `DateTime` property (i.e. `DataEntrada`) assigned to its default value (`DateTime.MinValue`), which is outside the minimum bound value of SQL `DATETIME` date type (note the equivalent for C# `DateTime` is `DATETIME2`) and triggering `SqlException`.

What you should do is putting `Html.BeginForm()` immediately after `@model` directive so that all form input elements are placed inside the form and use strongly-typed HTML helpers for all input elements which declared inside viewmodel class:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.BaseDados.ReservaVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="formBox">           
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>Registo de Reservas</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox ">
                                <div class="inputText">Nome*</div>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Cliente, null, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Telemóvel</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telemovel, new { @class = "input", id = "txtTelemovel" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Cartão Cidadão</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartaoCidadao, new { @class = "input", id = "txtCartaoCidadao" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox ">
                                <div class="inputText">ID Quarto</div>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Quarto, null, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Data Entrada*</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataEntrada, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Data Saída</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataSaida, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox ">
                                <div class="inputText">Nº Pessoas*</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroPessoas, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Nº Noites</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroNoites, new { @class = "input", id = "Noites" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Preço</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Preco, new { @class = "input" })
                                <br /><br /><br />
                                <div>*Campos Obrigatórios</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox">
                                <div class="inputText">Observações</div>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Observaçoes, new { @class = "input" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xl" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Registar"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Reservas")'" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Voltar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></button>
                        </center>
                    </div>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Then set required fields for viewmodel properties by using data annotations (i.e. `RequiredAttribute`):

**Model**

```
public class ReservaVM
{
    public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    public int ID_Quarto { get; set; }
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }
    public string CartaoCidadao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataEntrada { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NumeroPessoas { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
    public string Observaçoes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ReservaVM reserva)
{
    // do something
    return View(reserva);
}
```

By using this setup, your model binding should work as expected.

Comment: Now when you click on the button to register, it does a kind of refresh on the page and does not register anything.

Comment: Since you have 2 `Create` functions with different methods (one with `GET` and another with `POST`), set the form to perform POST request: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))`.

Comment: The problem is here  `<div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="inputBox ">
                                <div class="inputText">Nome*</div>
                                <input class="input" type="text" id="txtCliente" required>
                                <input type="hidden" id="ID_Cliente" name="ID_Cliente" />
                            </div>
                        </div>`

Comment: if using this    `<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Cliente, "ID_Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ID_Cliente", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>` it works. I want to use autocomplete.

Comment: Are you want something like `$('#ID_Cliente').autocomplete(...)`? Sounds like you're asking for different problem which should be asked in new question, I want to make sure that you're already solved current `DateTime` problem before moving to next issue.